# Dependency is missed in output after maven-assembly-plugin executed

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a problem using maven-assembly-plugin.

I want to get during package phase a directory with all project dependencies.
But I have a transitive dependency with compile scope which is missed from
assembly output directory.

The missed jar is batik-js-1.7.jar. Here is a dependency tree for this jar

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ sbercap-dependencies ---
[INFO] ru.spi2.test:sbercap-dependencies:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.7:compile
...
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-js:jar:1.7:compile
...
```

When assembly plugin is finished, others dependencies (batik-anim-1.7.jar, 
batik-css-1.7.jar) are added to output directory successfully. The batik-js-1.7.jar
is missed (screenshot attached).
[image: batik-js-1.7.jar is missed by maven-assembly-plugin]

On the other side, if I try to copy all dependencies using maven-dependency-plugin,
the batik-js-1.7.jar is successfully added to the folder (screenshot
 attached).
[image: batik-js-1.7.jar is added to the folder by maven-dependency-plugin]

Here is my dependencies and build blocks from pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/dependency-libs
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly-descriptor.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

The assembly descriptor is

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

    <id>assembly</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>


</assembly>
```

Could you explain me, am I doing something wrong? Why this library is missed
from assembly output?

I tried to find any similar problem in google but there were another problems -
dependency from test scope or missed dependency in pom.xml. Dependency set
useTransitiveDependencies property is true by default, so I don't really know 
why I get this result of assembly plugin.

My maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T22:49:05+03:00)
Maven home: C:\soft\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: ru_RU, platform encoding: Cp1251
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

maven-assembly-plugin version is 3.1.0

Could you help me, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with adding transitive dependency using maven-assembly-plugin if this dependency was declared in circular dependency.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MASSEMBLY/issues/MASSEMBLY-782

org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-...:1.7 has circular dependency between batik-bridge and batik-script.

You can choose several options to solve this problem.

1. Update to newer version of batik-... library which doesn't have any circular dependencies.
2. If you can't use previous option, you can configure pom.xml - exclude circular dependencies and extract them to have this dependencies as non-transitive.

   ```
   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>internal-module-groupId</groupId>
       <artifactId>internal-module-artifactId</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
               <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
               <artifactId>batik-script</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
       <artifactId>batik-script</artifactId>
       <version>1.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
       <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
       <version>1.7</version>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

Thanks to Thorsten Heit from maven users mailing list for the help.